# how to authenticate ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN separately in fos userbundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have made two different login section in my website, one for admin section and another for frontend users.

When I logged into to frontend it logged in. The problem is that when i try to login the admin section it throws access denied error.

Is it possible make two different login sessions so that both login session are independent of eachother

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you log in as a `ROLE_ADMIN`, you can build it such that it also inherits the `ROLE_USER` permission. No need to have separate login sessions.

Comment: Are you trying to login as 2 separate roles simultaneously in different tabs on your browser?

Comment: yes @George thats what i mean

Comment: I do that using 2 different browsers so it avoids the session issue.  This is only needed on the dev machine so I didnt build extra functionality for it

Answer (score 0):

you don't show security.yml, so no way to know for sure:

try deleting this row:

```
- { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

but most likely you have something like this in your security.yml

```
    access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

and your login page is on url /admin/login/

so it requires ROLE_ADMIN to access login page, before you can login as admin

Comment: i had done that already. The problem is that if i logged in into user account first then i cant logged into admin until i i logged out of user account

Comment: @BijeshShrestha but still it is many number of reasons for that, in my application when  you are logged as user you can enter admin login form and login as admin (this would change your security token from user to admin). So I guess that you have misconfiguration on admin login page that requires some permission to access it. maybe you require for admin page IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY permission. but this is just guessing not sensible approach to solving problem that is based on facts. so provide us with security.yml file config

Comment: here it goes,
access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$,    roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register,  roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin,     roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/,          roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/account,   roles: ROLE_USER }

Comment: @BijeshShrestha I've updated my answer, move this code to yours question (you can edit it). And it's not entire security config.